# Difference between s-t flow, value of flow and max flow in network flow

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand Network Flows by reading the Klienberg and Tardos book. I have a doubt with respect to understanding the following terms and how the values of these terms change whenever we perform augmentation. This is what I have understood till now. Please correct me if this is wrong

1. `s-t flow` - This is a random path `P` that can be found in any graph `G` to carry a flow from `s` to `t`
2. Value of the flow - This indicates the amount of flow generated by the source
3. Maximum flow - Here is where I have some problems. I am unable to understand the difference between value of a flow and the maximum flow. Does max flow indicate the sum of all `s-t` paths in a particular graph `G` that can carry traffic or does it indicate the maximum among these `s-t` paths?

Any help here would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Flow* is the sum of the flow along all edges out of *s* (or into *t*, which must necessarily be the same). The flow starts out at 0, and at various stages of a flow algorithm, it will gradually increase as we find more and more flow paths and add them to the overall flow. At some point, we can't find any more flow paths; then, we have obtained *maximum flow* (the maximum possible value of the flow). So the maximum flow is also the sum of the flow along all edges out of *s* (or into *t*), but only at the point where it is no longer possible to send more flow.

P.S. I don't have Kleinberg/Tardos, but are you sure that your definition of *s-t flow* is correct? If so, I understand that it sounds confusing, as "flow" typically refers to the overall flow. Cormen/Leiserson/Rivest/Stein uses what I believe to be the more common term *augmenting path*.

Comment: This is what the Kleinberg and Tardos book says - One often refers to any s - t path in the residual graph as an augmenting path. You can use it interchangeably.